# Jquery Popup (on general use of Jquery widgets)

Tags: jquery, popup, widget

My question is, I'm trying to use the Popup widget, which seems to be part of the Jquery Mobile package, but not stated if its part of the non-mobile jquery package.

I'm trying to build a Jquery Popup very similar to the examples here:
http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.0/popup-iframe/

My website has already been a long user of the normal jquery js file. 
**jquery-1.11.0.min.js**

I copy pasted the code examples from the jquerymobile website for my desktop site but it does not work. The popup iframe shows immediately when I load the page.

How can i tell if the popup widget is already included in my jquery file? Must I get the jquerymobile js file just for this purpose?

Cheers
Kevin

Answer (score 1):

What do you references to jQuery look like?  Sounds like you included a reference to the "core" but might not have referenced jQuery mobile (which I believe would make sure your popup gets registered as such to jQuery).

Can you post your references?

Comment: true this was probably the case

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you want to use that library you must include jquerymobile js file first. Look at the demo pages, the file is always included.

Answer (score 0):

Yes thats probably the case.

I resorted to using Colorbox instead, was much easier to plug and play.
http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/